# Extremely Long TTFB on ASP.net running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-testing

I am currently building a website of the creation of custom computers however I have the problem that my TTFB is very slow when running on my home IIS server. I have multiple websites running on this server and this is the only one with a 20-30s TTFB.

I have used [webpagetest.org](https://www.webpagetest.org/) to test my website and am getting [this water fall image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRbWl.png).

However I then tester my website on debug using VS and chrome's own Dev Tools and my [water fall here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxccI.png) give me 1 second. I was wondering how to diagnose and test for the issues either on the server or in my page that may be causing this.
Here is a snippet of my home page code for anyone wondering-
Controller:

```
namespace ComputerSite.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Layout (The only part of the page without static content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Computers for you!</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/boot")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajaxgroup")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tawk")
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    string text = UserHelper.GetUserEmail(User.Identity.Name), key = "MY APIKEY";
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

    Byte[] textBytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    Byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    Byte[] hashBytes;

    using (System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes)) { hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(textBytes); }

    string hashTxt = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
        Tawk_API.setAttributes({
        'name' : '@User.Identity.Name',
            'email': '@UserHelper.GetUserEmail(User.Identity.Name)',
        'hash': '@hashTxt'
}, function (error) {});

};
    </script>
}
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_navBar"); }
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Building computer for you by you!</p>
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As requested I created a brand new ASP.net website and debugged it, from this I got a [waterfall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tCfc.png) with a load time of 270 ms and TTFB of 12ms

Comment: What does `UserHelper.GetUserEmail` do? 30 seconds screams a timeout of some description. Is it attempting to go to the database and the database server is not there / not accessible, e.g. it's trying to access your dev server?

Comment: @Rob Get email does connect to the database to get the user's email using an entity framework context however I am still getting a 30 second wait time even if the request is not authenticated and that code doesn't run.

Comment: @mjwills The question I am asking is why is it 1 second on my debug machine (the same website) which is 30s on my server.

Comment: Learn tools like performance profiler, Wireshark and Fiddler, and then you can measure the performance of your web page/network with more insights. Otherwise, such questions over SO are pointless and impossible to answer.